# PHP & MySQL username validation and storage problem

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason when a user enters a brand new username the error message `<p>Username unavailable</p>` is displayed and the name is not stored. I was wondering if some can help find the flaw in my code so I can fix this error? Thanks

Here is the PHP code.

```
if($_POST['username'] && trim($_POST['username'])!=='') {
    $u = "SELECT * 
          FROM users 
          WHERE username  = '$username'
          AND user_id <> '$user_id'";
    $r = mysqli_query ($mysqli, $u) or trigger_error("Query: $u\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($mysqli));

    if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == TRUE) {
        echo '<p>Username unavailable</p>';
        $_POST['username'] = NULL;
    } else if(isset($_POST['username']) && mysqli_num_rows($r) == 0 && strlen($_POST['username']) <= 255) { 
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['username']);
    } else if($_POST['username'] && strlen($_POST['username']) >= 256) {
        echo '<p>Username can not exceed 255 characters</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you're trying to achieve? Not code-wise but the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Hey, mysqli_num_rows will **always** be true since your query is valid. Instead, you have to check the number of rows that it has returned, which should be zero of course if you'd like to create a new user. Therefore, check if the number of rows equals to 1.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) echo "<p>Username unavailable</p>"; $_POST['username'] = NULL;
```

Or do it this way:

```
if (mysql_i_num_rows($r) == 0 ) {
  // There isn't a user with this username yet, so create new user
} else {
  echo "Username not available";
}
```

Comment: I am not sure about that. In PHP false, 0 and null are all equal to each other. So if the value is checked as true than it should be greater than 0.

In other words:
if($val == false); if($val == 0); if($val == ""); and if($val == null);
Are all the same.

If the string contains any value (other than false/zero/null) than it is true.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, it's a bad practice compare it with TRUE because it always return an int, use instead:

```
mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not specified the values of `$username` and `$user_id`, your code of

```
$u = "SELECT * 
          FROM users 
          WHERE username  = '$username'
          AND user_id <> '$user_id'";
```

will evaluate to

```
$u = "SELECT * 
              FROM users 
              WHERE username  = ''
              AND user_id <> ''";
```

I would guess that this was not your intended query, and you will be retrieving all entries with a blank user name.